# Want to inactivate the "Disable"/ "Uninstall" button for my VS extension

Tags: vsix

I have created a vsix extension and i want to make the "Disable" button inactive. So that user can not disable or uninstall it.

Here is example what i exactly want to achieve for my extension.

[image]

Comment: I have created one vsix, Extension for my Visual Studio 2015. Which Appears in place where all extensions are available. When we click on that then two button appears one is Disable and another is Uninstall. As you can see in image in this only one button "Uninstall" appears for extension Infragistics and is inactive so that user can not uninstall it. I am looking for My Extension also appear but buttons inactive, so that they can not uninstall or disable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to change how that button actually works. If you install your extension via a custom installer (.MSI) (and set the InstalledByMsi attribute in your .vsixmanifest), or if you specify the AllUsers attribute in your .vsixmanifest, this button should be disabled by default. Unless you run the IDE as Admin, in which case the user will be allowed to uninstall the VSIX.

Sincerely,